# How to escape double quote in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to do parse a string `Hello " test` containing double quote which already escaped, but I get an error

```
JSON.parse(`{"x":"Hello \" test "}`)
```

Is there anything I missed here?

[image]

```js
JSON.parse(`{"x":"Hello \" test "}`)
```

Comment: Can you try ```JSON.parse(`{"x":"Hello \\" test "}`)```

Comment: There is 2 backslashes

Comment: @DownloadPizza yeah works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape  the backslash `\`, so it turns into two backslashes `\\`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"x":"Hello \\" test"}'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let mydata = `{"x":"Hello \" test "}`
 
let escapeJsonFunc = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\/g,'\\');
};


console.log( escapeJsonFunc(mydata) )
```

Comment: That's still a JSON string - the OP want's it parsed.